# Adding test method template in android studio doesn't work?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

**Hi guys**,

when I want to generate code template in the android studio testing environment, the template will not add for me,it only shows me the edit template option like below

[image: insert option doesn't showing]

seem like android studio doesn't allow me to add code template for junit4
as you can see the plus button is also disabled for me, anybody know why?

[image: Look at the Plus button]

Answer (score 0):

Just press `enter`, without click on right arrow, then code will be generated according to your template.